# Visual Studio 2010 and 2013 not working on my system

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, vb.net-2010

I apologize as this may seem as bit of a general question.

I have developed a couple of VB programs using Visual Studio 2010 Professional and others on Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.  While I have not done any work in about a month with either version of Visual Studio, I thought I would go in and start work on a new project.

After entering some code in Visual Studio 2010 using WinForms, I found I was unable to run the code in the debugger (pressed the start button and F5).

It acted like it would start, then it just stopped and returned back to my code.

I thought I would try it on another program that was completed and working a couple of months ago, but I had the same issue present itself.  Attempting to use Visual Studio 2013 had the same effect.

Any ideas from anyone?  Has anyone else experienced this same issue recently?  Once again, I do apologize for the lack of examples here, but I'm not sure what I can include to show the problem.

Comment: is it prompting any error / warning message or in output window ?

Comment: That is the odd thing, there are no messages showing up in the error window.  I'm at a complete loss on this one!  I'm hoping I don't have to uninstall and reinstall the programs.

Comment: Also have you installed/uninstalled any other software lately?

Comment: Are there any errors in the Event Viewer?

Comment: Hello all,

I ended up doing a reinstall of Visual Studio 2010 Pro and at first ended up with the same issue. When I ran it, though, I noticed I did not get the prompt showing it was being run as an administrator. This had actually been set before, but had somehow changed.  When I changed it to run as administrator, it started working just fine.  I'll try the same with VS 2013 later.

I do appreciate all the fine suggestions. I have installed other software lately, so that may have changed a setting in the registry. I'm not certain that there were any errors in the Event Viewer.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you should try resetting visual studio settings (and a restart may solve the issue)

you can try following

1. do it via visual studio -> tools -> import export settings
2. or you can run this command devenv /resetuserdata
3. or checkout this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273.aspx

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try and post the results here.  It is late here, so I will not be able to attempt this until the morning.  Thanks again, Baljeetsingh!

Comment: @Mike sure, btw reset settings via visual studio will be done very quick should be less then 2 mins and is harmless , dont forget to save your settings when you run the wizard.